# Component.defaults undefined on creating ractive js component

Tags: ractivejs

I'm trying to create a new ractive component in my project, just as a simple test case. However, when the section containing the component is rendered, I get an error in ractive.js saying that Component.defaults is undefined in the line

```
adapt = combineAdaptors( root, Component.defaults.adapt, Component.adaptors );
```

In fact, the only thing in the Component object is the component that I added.

For reference, I'm using Ractive.js 4.0.

```
// productComponent.js
define(['ractive', 'rv!accordion/productComponent'], function(Ractive) {

    var productComponent = {};

    // add module properties here
    productComponent.ProductComponent = Ractive.extend({

        template: productComponent,

        init: function(options) {
                console.log('init');
        },

        data: {

        }

    });

    Ractive.components.productComponent = productComponent.ProductComponent;

    return productComponent;
});
```

Then in the parent ractive, I have:

```
components: {
    'productComponent': productComponent
}
```

Where productComponent is a reference to the productComponent.js file

The template uses this to create the component in a loop

```
{{#items:key}} 
    <productComponent product="{{product}}" />
{{/items}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to return the `productComponent.ProductComponent` constructor (rather than `productComponent`) from productComponent.js, if that's how it's being referred to in the parent (the `components:{}` option on the parent overrides `Ractive.components.productComponent`).

Also, if you're using rv.js, you'd refer to the template like so:

```js
// productComponent.js
define(['ractive', 'rv!accordion/productComponent'], function(Ractive, template) {

    var productComponent = {};

    // add module properties here
    productComponent.ProductComponent = Ractive.extend({

        template: template, // <---- note this...

        init: function(options) {
                console.log('init');
        },

        data: {

        }

    });

    Ractive.components.productComponent = productComponent.ProductComponent;

    return productComponent.ProductComponent; // <---- ...and this!
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you. I knew it was probably something simple.